# Partial Templates Location in Phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon

Where should [partial templates](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/views.html#using-partials) files be placed in Phalcon? Is there any config for that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Partials*

They have to be under the `view` folder. An example structure is below:

```
views/
    about/      <- AboutController
    index/      <- IndexController
    contact/    <- ContactController
    layouts/    <- Templates to override or add to the current template process
    partials/   <- (name can be anything) where you store your partials
```

If you want your partials to be in a specific subfolder then you will need to define it in the partial argument

```
$this->partial('partials/header');
```

The above will look for a file in the `views/partials` folder by the name of `header.phtml` or `header.volt` or whatever your registered view engine is. (phtml is the default).

**NOTE** You are not restricted to use a folder to add your partials in. They can happily be in the `views` folder on their own. You can organize your `views` folder the way you see fit.

The `layouts` folder under `views` contains templates that can be used anywhere in the flow of the application but are not partials. Think of them as addons to your current template flow.

A layout called `main` template would be invoked in the controller layer as such:

```
$this->view->setTemplateAfter('main');
```

If you navigate to say `/about/index`, Phalcon will pick the `views\index.volt` file, then the `layouts\main.volt` and finally the `views\about\index.volt`

**NOTE** Again I am using the volt example above - it could easily be phtml or any other View engine you use (phtml is the default).

HTH